# Java system trayicon mouselistener

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, trayicon

Here is the code. I want to ask why is that `mouseClicked`  for a trayicon works perfectly but `mouseEntered` won't work at all?

```
mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            showStage(stage);
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // why this cant be triggerd
        trayIcon.displayMessage(
            "警告", "这是一个警告提示!", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
    }
};
trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Comment: You need to add your mouse adapter as a mouse motion listener as well

Comment: It still does not work mouseMotionListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("out");
                        }
              
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("in");
                        }
                    };    trayIcon.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotionListener);                           but if I use MouseMotionAdapter it works in  mouseMoved but I cant tell it if mouseEnter  or mouseExited

Comment: Please show the type you have on your mouseListener .

Comment: nothing special 。private static MouseListener mouseListener;  it is from java.awt.event

Comment: That's why. Change it to  MouseAdapter, which implements both interfaces, as I wrote below

Answer (score 0):

After

```
trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

add this line:

```
trayIcon.addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);
```

Comment: addMouseMotionListener
(java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener)
in TrayIcon cannot be applied
to
(java.awt.event.MouseListener)

Comment: The type of your mouseListener is probably wrong. Set it to MouseAdapter.